# Spring Hibernate @Data update vs raw UPDATE query: Optimistic Lock Exception despite @Transactional?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I am working with Spring Hibernate ORM for Data Management with MYSQL DBMS using my Java Spring application. I have a simple requirement - when someone uses my application, I will increase a counter in my database by 1, so I can track my users' usage count.

I have two brief implementations here I would like to discuss, one gives me an Optimistic Lock Exception under high load (I created a simulation of many concurrent users to test load) and one does not. Could someone guide me in understanding the differences, the reasons behind such behaviours, and whether data correctness is ensured?

Here is my fist code sample. Under a stress test, OptimisticLockException is thrown.

```
@Transactional
public void updateLog() {
    ConnectionUseLog log = getLog();
    log.setCount(log.getCount() + 1);
    // ... other unrelated updates to database
}
```

Here ConnectionUseLog is a @Data class with @Version attribute for optimistic locking and a 'count' attribute (this is what I am incrementing by 1).

```
@Data
public class ConnectionUseLog {
    @Version
    @Column(name="optlock_version")
    Integer version;
    @Column(name="count")
    Integer count;
}
```

- getLog() is a raw SELECT query I have written, getting the row which I want. It uses a PagingAndSortingRepository interface from springframework.data.repository.
- getCount(...) gets value in the column, method is autogenerated.
- setCount(...) updates the count, method is autogenerated.

Now in the next example, it is much simpler, plain and simple a raw UPDATE query (not SELECT as before) to the database - no problems. Raw query is also embedded through a PagingAndSortingRepository interface from springframework.data.repository as previous example.

```
@Transactional
public void updateDailyLog() {
    incrementCount(1);
    // ... other unrelated updates to database
}
```

Why does one have optimistic concurrency problems, when both are wrapped in @Transactional?

Can someone help understand the difference and help me weigh both approaches? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that `@Transactional` should make your `OptimisticLockingException` go away. 
Optimistic locking is all about concurrency of different transactions.

It works by incrementing a version in each transaction and also checking on updates that the version is still unchanged from when the entity was loaded.

Under high load this often fails for series of the events like this one:

1. Transaction 1 (T1) loads a row say with version 23.
2. Transaction 2 (T2) loads the same row with the same version 23.
3. T1 updates the count, increasing the value to 24 and commits making the changed value visible to other transactions.
4. T2 tries to update the row as well, but the version is no longer 23 so you get an optimistic locking exception.
5. You should restart T2 until it succeeds to actually update the database.

Note that neither transaction puts a blocking lock on the row.
This is in most cases a good thing since it improves performance.
This benefit goes away if number 4 happens to often.

When you do the "raw UPDATE" which I guess is something like `UPDATE log set counter = counter + 1 WHERE ...` there is no optimistic locking going on.
Instead you are using basically pessimistic locking: You lock the row you want to update when you read it.
This happens implicitly since read and write happen in the same statement.
This means a similar process like above will now happen as follows:

1. Transaction 1 (T1) updates a row locking it.
2. Transaction 2 (T2) tries to update the same row but gets blocked by the lock and has to wait.
3. T1 commits its transaction making changes visible to other transactions and releasing the lock.
4. T2 can now proceed and updates the row based on the changed value from T1.

The lock limits the throughput of your application, especially when the transactions are long and if rows get locked that actually don't get updated in the end.
This isn't the case in your example but in the more typical example of a user loading a row to look at it and maybe edit it it is much more common.

In your case the approach with a direct update seems to be more suitable.
Just make sure that the transactions are as short as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought @Transactional provides a lock but that is not the case as you are explaining. Can I say that the raw UPDATE delegates the lock management to the DBMS? In other words lock management is removed from the ORM.

Comment: What ever you do, all the locks involved are done by the DBMS and only triggered by the ORM. The clue really is: with Optimistic Locking there is (almost) no lock.

Comment: Also, what if I used the synchronize keyword on function with the code with optimistic locking? Do you think it would be a big misstep? Will performance be worse than the pessimistic lock of the other implementation?

Comment: Not a good idea. Putting this stuff in a synchronized block means you are doing a pessimistic lock but now on the java side. This makes the duration of the transaction longer, since it now also includes the network round trip.

If the direct update is to slow you might be able to do something like doing the increments in a local AtomicLong and just occasionally write it to the database. Of course this carries the risk of loosing information in case of something going haywire.